# Can I trap the Informatica Amazon S3Bucket name doesn’t match standards

Tags: amazon-redshift, informatica-powercenter

In Informatica we have mapping source qualifiers connecting to Amazon Web Services—AWS.

We often and erratically get a failure that our s3 bucket names do not comply with naming standards.   We restart the workflows again and they continue on every time successfully.

Is there a way to trap for this specifically and then maybe call a command object to restart the workflow command via PMCMD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... It's possible for example to have workflow one (W1):

```
your_session --> cmd_touch_file_if_session_failed
```

and another workflow (W2), running continuously:

```
event_wait_for_W1_file --> pmcmd_restart_W1 --> delete_watch_file
```

Although it would be a lot better to nail down the cause for your failures and get it resolved.

Comment: I completely agree... we are a decently large shop and were told by Infa that we need to upgrade. With Redshift, it will be painful re-configuring every source-qualifier.  On this new workflow job I am creating, I will implement this solution.  It looks perfect for my needs.  Thank you.  I see your Certified Informatica badge is gone.

Comment: Replaced with something more original ;) Have you been thinking about exporting, mass-editing and importing back to a new folder for example? And if you like the solution - I don't, honestly ;) - can you mark it?

Comment: I understand your dissatisfaction in the solution.  I had something similar so you showed me I was not missing something obvious that I hadn't thought of.  That's worthy.  I was already restarting my job on failures, but I really wanted to restart when I 'knew' it was the s3bucket error, and not just any fatal error.

Answer (score 2):

How are you starting the workflows in regular runs?

If you are using a shell script, you can add a logic to restart if you see a particular error. I have created a script a while ago to restart workflows for a particular error.

In a nut shell it works like this

```
start workflow (with pmcmd)

#in case of an error 

check repository db and get the error
if the error is specific to s3 bucket name
restart the workflow
```

Comment: I would absolutely love that... professional... thank you.

Comment: I got it... I had my WF looping.  So, WF1 starts W2 after 1-min wait.  When W2 finishes, it knows if it needs to keep going, so it will call W1 again.  I am new to Informatica and am not real strong in scripts.  Do most people have scripts like this to start workflows?  Mine is simply going to be schedule.  I definitely want to be able to trap this S3bucket error.  Even Informatica technical folks are not sure what is happening.  So we watch our jobs and restart them manually.  Arghhh.... I wanted to make my jobs smarter and be self-managing on that error.